# TimeZoneInfo in WinApi return bad value

Tags: c#, uwp

It seems that I found a mistake in WinApi. When I use TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName in Debug in my Visual Studio 2015 it return right variant to me, as example "(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius". In release mode(.net native)  same api return me "FLE Standard Time". Be greatfull to hear how to get time zone information in other way, or how to fix this issue.

Comment: I can't have reproduced it, got `"(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd (RTZ 2)"` in both (debug and release) cases. Visual Studio 2015, target .Net Framework 4.5.1

Comment: The probability for a bug in the Windows API is many, many orders of magnitude lower, than for a bug in client code. We need to see **your** code.

Comment: Under the answer in comment I poste solution with problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have missed something in your code. One mistake that I made before, and is easy to make is confusing `DisplayName` with `DaylightName`:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timeZoneName = TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName; //FLE Standard Time
            var displayName = TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName; //(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius
        }
```

For reference, you can check [Time Zone IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx)

Comment: Your help me with Time Zone IDs link! Now I can made converter. But I'am shure that use DisplayName instead DaylightName. And problem in debug/release mod. So i think it is not my code mistake.

Comment: That is strange. I can't reproduce the issue myself, I have the exact same results both in Debug and Release mode. Maybe you can provide some details about your environment and some code?

Comment: Now I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3(issue was on 2 update too). I just create clear [UWP c# project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzv71ag7e45v301/TimeZoneTest.rar?dl=0), and problem still exist. Windows 10(10.0.10586.494)

Comment: I admit I was skeptical, but it does happen as you said it does. Didn't have time to look much into [TimeZoneInfo sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/e843d7bcccb8a815.html), but it seems that for some reason, in UWP projects, TimeZoneInfo fails to get details of timezone, and falls back to this behavior (maybe something to do with Win 10 developer mode).

Comment: Main problem that at first I wtite about this issue to [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/ed643e08-1ec3-4c23-b0dd-4f010eff27e0/problem-with-timezoneinfo?forum=windbg) and no one answer =(Thanks for your help, at least a made converter for time zone id in english language.